# setting back camera default position when returning scene

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I am currently using aframe to do scene changing within a single html file. 
Eg, I have a lobby, then i can navigate to scene 2, within scene 2 i can go back to lobby by activating the back to lobby button. This will bring me back to the lobby scene , however the camera position is left off from where the previous back to lobby button was. 
Is there any way I can enforce that my camera will go back to the default view that i want it to be, upon return to the lobby scene?

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html class="a-html">

    <head>
      <title>new change</title>
      <meta aframe-injected="" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no,user-scalable=no,minimal-ui"><meta aframe-injected="" name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"><meta aframe-injected="" name="theme-color" content="black">
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aframe/0.5.0/aframe.js"></script>
      <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@^4.0.0/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <a-scene class="fullscreen" canvas="" inspector="" keyboard-shortcuts="" screenshot="" vr-mode-ui="" auto-enter-vr="">

                <a-entity camera="" position="0 0 5" look-controls="" wasd-controls="" rotation="" scale="" visible="">
                        <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 1000" position="0 0 -1" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03" material="color: black; shader: flat"       rotation="" scale="" visible="" raycaster="">
                        <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="backwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1"></a-animation>
                        <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="forwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1"></a-animation>
                      </a-entity>
                </a-entity>  <!--End of Camera entity -->


                 <a-entity id="scene1">
                         <a-text value="Lobby" position="-1.5 5 -3" scale="2 2" color="black"></a-text>
                         <a-sky color="skyblue" position="0 0 0" rotation="" scale="" visible="" material="" geometry=""></a-sky>

                        <a-box color="tomato" onclick="setScene2()" position="0 1 -3" depth="2" height="4" width="0.5"><a-text value="hello world"></a-text></a-box> <!--box1 -->

                        <a-box color="tomato" onclick="setScene3()" position="2 1 -3" depth="2" height="4" wlocalidth="0.5"></a-box> <!--box2 -->

                        <a-box color="tomato" onclick="setScene4()" position="4 1 -3" depth="2" height="4" width="0.5"></a-box> <!--box3 -->

                 </a-entity> <!--End of scene1 entity -->


                 <a-entity id="scene2" visible="false">
                        <a-sky color="yellow" position="0 0 0" rotation="" scale="" visible="" material="" geometry=""></a-sky>

                        <a-box color="pink" onclick="setScene1()" position="-3 1 -3"  rotation="0 90 0 " depth="2" height="4" width="0.5">
                            <a-text value="Return to Lobby" position="-1 0 -0.5" color="black" rotation="0 -90 0" ></a-text>    

                        </a-box> <!-- End of scene2, calling returning to scene1-->


                        <a-box scale="1 1 1" color="skyblue" position="3 0 -5" rotation="45 45 45">
                            <a-animation attribute="position" to="3 0.5 -5" direction="alternate" dur="2000" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation> 
                            <a-animation attribute="scale" begin="mouseenter" dur="200" to="2.3 2.3 2.3"></a-animation>
                            <a-animation attribute="scale" begin="mouseleave" dur="200" to="2 2 2"></a-animation>
                            <a-animation attribute="rotation" begin="click" dur="2000" to=" 360 405 45" ></a-animation>


                        </a-box>
                          <a-plane color="#CCC" height="2" width="2"></a-plane>
                          <a-circle color="black" radius="0.75" depth="0.5" position="0 -3 2" rotation="-90 0  0"></a-circle>
                        <a-text value="Welcome to Scene 2" position="-1.5 5 -3" scale="2 2" color="black"></a-text>

                 </a-entity> <!--End of scene2 entity -->


                 <a-entity id="scene3" visible ="false">

                        <a-sky color="limegreen" position="0 0 0" rotation="" scale="" visible="" material="" geometry=""></a-sky>

                        <a-box color="blue" onclick="setScene1()" position="-3 1 -3"  rotation="0 90 0 " depth="2" height="4" width="0.5">
                            <a-text value="Return to Lobby" position="-1 0 -0.5" color="black" rotation="0 -90 0" ></a-text>    

                        </a-box> <!-- End of scene2, calling returning to scene1-->
                          <a-plane color="#CCC" height="2" width="2"></a-plane>

                        <a-box scale="1 1 1" color="skyblue" position="3 0 -5" rotation="45 45 45">
                            <a-animation attribute="position" to="3 10.5 -5" direction="alternate" dur="2000" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation> 
                            <a-animation attribute="scale" begin="mouseenter" dur="200" to="2.3 2.3 2.3"></a-animation>
                            <a-animation attribute="scale" begin="mouseleave" dur="200" to="2 2 2"></a-animation>
                            <a-animation attribute="rotation" begin="click" dur="2000" to=" 360 405 45" ></a-animation>
                        </a-box>

                        <a-text value="Welcome to Scene 3" position="-1.5 5 -3" scale="2 2" color="black"></a-text>


                 </a-entity>





            </a-scene>

 <script type="text/javascript">



  function setScene2() {
    // console.log('kkk')
    document.getElementById('scene1').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
    document.getElementById('scene2').setAttribute('visible', 'true')

    // document.querySelector('#ambient2').emit('aaa');
    // document.querySelector('#fading-cube').emit('fade');
  }
  function setScene1() {
    // console.log('kkk')
    document.getElementById('scene2').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
    document.getElementById('scene1').setAttribute('visible', 'true')
    document.getElementById('scene3').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
    // document.querySelector('#ambient1').emit('aaa');
    // document.querySelector('#fading-cube').emit('fade');
  }
  function setScene3(){
    document.getElementById('scene1').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
    document.getElementById('scene3').setAttribute('visible', 'true')

  }


  </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, your camera is at `0 0 5`. If You want to return to that position, just change the position to the default every time You 'switch scenes'. Which is actually changing visibility of entity wrappers.

If Your camera had an id `camera`, you could grab it like this:

```
function setScene2() {
  // console.log('kkk')
  document.getElementById('scene1').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
  document.getElementById('scene2').setAttribute('visible', 'true')
  document.getElementById('camera').setAttribute('position', '0 0 5')
  // document.querySelector('#ambient2').emit('aaa');
  // document.querySelector('#fading-cube').emit('fade');
}

function setScene1() {
  // console.log('kkk')
  document.getElementById('scene2').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
  document.getElementById('scene1').setAttribute('visible', 'true')
  document.getElementById('scene3').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
  document.getElementById('camera').setAttribute('position', '0 0 5')
  // document.querySelector('#ambient1').emit('aaa');
  // document.querySelector('#fading-cube').emit('fade');
}

function setScene3() {
  document.getElementById('scene1').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
  document.getElementById('scene3').setAttribute('visible', 'true')
  document.getElementById('camera').setAttribute('position', '0 0 5')
}
```

otherwise You'd have to grab it by `document.querySelector([camera]).`

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls6ebj29/).

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying, however, is it possible to show me example how it is done? I wanted to use common class method, but not sure how to do it. Thus I tried placing camera entity in scene2 and scene3, however, it doesnt work. I still couldnt make it fix at the starting default camera position upon return back to the lobby scene.

Comment: @KeithOng sorry, I just saw that You actually don't have different scenes, but different entities that are switching visibility. I've updated my anwser + fiddle.